# How to iterate over a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, hash, loops

I'm dealing with an xml like this:

```
<fare_master_pricer_reply>  
 <flight_index>

  <group_of_flights>
    <flight_details>
    </flight_details>
    .
    .
    <flight_details>
    </flight_details>   
   </group_of_flights>

  <group_of_flights>
    <flight_details>
    </flight_details>
    .
    .
    <flight_details>
    </flight_details>   
   </group_of_flights>
     .    
     .   
   <group_of_flights>
    <flight_details>
    </flight_details>
    .
    .
    <flight_details>
    </flight_details>   
   </group_of_flights>  
  </flight_index> 
 </fare_master_pricer_reply>
```

That is given to me in a hash object. I need to iterate over that hash and so far I've coded this:

```
@flights = response.to_hash[:fare_master_pricer_calendar_reply][:flight_index]
while (@flight_groups = @flights[:group_of_flights]) != nil
  while (@flight = @flight_groups[:flight_details])
    @time_data = @flight[:flight_information][:product_date_time]
    @html = "<tr>"
    @html += "<td>" + @time_data[:date_of_departure] + "</td>"
    @html += "<td>" + @time_data[:date_of_arrival] + "</td>"
    @html += "<td>" + @flight[:location][:location_id] + "</td>"
    @html += "</tr>"
  end
  @html = "<tr><td>**</td><td>**</td><td>**</td><td>**</td><td>**</td><td>**</td><td>**</td></td>"
end
```

but I get

> TypeError (Symbol as array index):

in this line:

```
while (@flight = @flight_groups[:flight_details])
```

Why my hash is becoming an array? Is this the right way to iterate over my original hash?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at your XML:

```
<fare_master_pricer_reply>  
 <flight_index>
  <group_of_flights>
   <!--...-->
  </group_of_flights>
  <group_of_flights>
   <!--...-->
  </group_of_flights>
  <group_of_flights>
   <!--...-->
  </group_of_flights>
  <!--...-->
```

So `<flight_index>` contains a list of `<group_of_flights>` elements. That would naturally be represented as an array, not a hash.

Then, you do this:

```
@flights = response.to_hash[:fare_master_pricer_calendar_reply][:flight_index]
```

And that is equivalent to this:

```
h = response.to_hash
@flights = [:fare_master_pricer_calendar_reply][:flight_index]
```

So `@flights` ends up with the contents of `<flight_index>`. As noted above, `<flight_index>` is just a container for a list of `<group_of_flights>` elements and your XML mangler is probably converting that list to the most natural representation of a list, that would give you an instance of Array rather than a Hash.

You don't want to iterate over `@flights` as a Hash, iterate over it as an Array instead. You'll probably face the same situation with the inner `<flight_details>` elements.

Comment: And how should I iterate over that array? Because I need to know the "key" values in order to do what I want to do (that is build a table that represents my xml data)

Comment: @content01: Probably `@flights.each { |g| ... }`, that will give you the `<group_of_flights>` data in `g`, then another `g.each` to get at the contained `<flight_details>`, etc.

Comment: The thing is, inside each <group_of_flights> exist more tags than just <flight_details>. How can I get the <flight_details> inside the outer loop?

Comment: @content01: You can access the `@flights` and `g` as needed in the inner blocks as they'd still be in scope.

Answer (score 10):

The correct way to iterate over a hash is like so

```
@flights.each do |key, value|
end
```

See [Hash#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000742)